# Regex expression to get value after = symbol in string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using an API which returns a response as shown below

```
#
#Thu Oct 03 22:47:55 CEST 2019
AUTHTOKEN=afibfd74y3bfbdiufh
RESULT=TRUE
```

I want to get the two values (AUTHTOKEN, RESULT) separately from the string using a regex expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
.*\nAUTHTOKEN=(.*)\nRESULT=(.*)/gm
```